# Animation Arrow in android, start and stop

Tags: android

I have been created the animation arrow. When I press the button then it rotate -45 degree and then goes back arrow. 
My Question is: I want to stop the arrow at -45 degree. When I click the button again then it should move the arrow -45 to -90 and so on.
Please help me regarding this problem. thanks

I am placing code here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">

        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:toDegrees="-45"
            android:toYScale="0.0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:duration="400"


             />
    </set>
```

---

### hyperspace_jump.xml

```
package kh.qasim;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CustomAnimationActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        final Animation hyperspaceJump = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.hyperspace_jump);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    image.startAnimation(hyperspaceJump);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

---

### CustomAnimationActivity.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:src="@drawable/up" android:layout_width="203dp" android:layout_height="148dp"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

### main.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want to prevent you image to revert to previous state afterb the animation, you need to use :

```
anim.setFillAfter(true);
```

Also, in order to be able to change orientation dynamically, you should create your animation programmatically, instead of doing it from an XML file :

```
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(fromDegrees, toDegrees);
```

Use fromDegress and toDegrees variable to control the start and end orientation of your object. For instance, you could put save the current orientation in a variable that you would call currentOrientation. So, you just need to call :

```
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(cuurentOrientation, currentOrientation - 45);
```

Then start the animation like you did before.

At the end of the animation, just store the new orientation in currentOrientation.

Comment: but your solution give the external rotation. but I want inner rotation.

Comment: What do you mean by "inner rotation" ?

Comment: 'inner rotation' mean center of image should not be move. image should be move on own center.

Comment: Android official doc says "You can specify the point to use for the center of the rotation, where (0,0) is the top left point. If not specified, (0,0) is the default rotation". So, if you want the rotation to be computed from the center of the image instead of its top left point, you can use pivotX and pivotY parameters in RotateAnimation constructor. For instance : new RotateAnimation(cuurentOrientation, currentOrientation - 45, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f)